# Are astronomical events the only way to obtain starcharts?

Tags: kittens-game

Every now and then an "A rare astronomical event occured in the sky" happens. When I click Observe I get a starchart.

One of the things I can use them for is trade ships.

Is that(astronomical event) the only way to obtain starcharts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Resources&redirect=no): **yes**.

> starchart - found by observing rare astronomical events after researching Astronomy tech

According to the code (of this version (0.9.6.9): **yes**. There is no other mention of starcharts, only in the workshop (as required researching resource) and the astronomical events. Note that the observatories can auto-observe these events, and therefor you can end up with a lot of charts if you let the game running overnight.

Comment: As of couple of weeks ago, you can also get starcharts by launching satellites into the orbit (you obviously need to reach the space era first). Each satellite produces 0.005 starcharts / second and increase Observatory effectiveness by 5%.

Answer (score 3):

New information (sourced from[wiki page](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=starchart))

Starcharts are produced by:

> Get more by building Observatories, Research Vessels, Space Beacons, launching satellites or from kitten Scholars with the Astrophysicists upgrade.

- Observatories simultaneously boost the chance of events and give a small chance to automatically observe them
- Research Vessels have a 0.05/sec production of star charts. Does not appear to be upgradeable
- Space Beacons have 0.125/sec production of star charts. Also does not appear to be upgradeable
- Satellites have a .005/sec production of star charts. Can be upgraded by 30% with Hubble Space Telescope
- Scholar kittens can get the Astrophysicist upgrade for .0005/sec production

ver 1.4.4.2